# Using ZIPFoundation, how to add a file to an archive at desired path?

Tags: swift, zip, zipfoundation

I'm trying to add a file to an archive in Swift using the ZIPFoundation lib.

The archive looks like this:

```
/
/folder1/
/folder2/ <-- Move file here.
```

Currently using this to add my file to the archive, but I don't get the logic of the parameters:

```swift
public func addEntry(with path: String, relativeTo baseURL: URL)
```

Creating an `Archive` object and adding the file using `addEntry()`, is there a way to not just add the file to the root path of the archive?

Code Edit:

```
internal func moveLicense(from licenseUrl: URL, to publicationUrl: URL) throws {
    guard let archive = Archive(url: publicationUrl, accessMode: .update) else  {
        return
    }
    // Create local folder to have the same path as in the archive.
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var urlMetaInf = licenseUrl.deletingLastPathComponent()
    
    urlMetaInf.appendPathComponent("META-INF", isDirectory: true)
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: urlMetaInf, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    
    let uuu = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlMetaInf.path, isDirectory: true)
    // move license in the meta-inf folder.
    try fileManager.moveItem(at: licenseUrl, to: uuu.appendingPathComponent("license.lcpl"))
    // move dir
    print(uuu.lastPathComponent.appending("/license.lcpl"))
    print(uuu.deletingLastPathComponent())
    do {
    try archive.addEntry(with: uuu.lastPathComponent.appending("license.lcpl"), // Missing '/' before license
                         relativeTo: uuu.deletingLastPathComponent())
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
// This is still testing code, don't mind the names :)
```

Comment: If the error is printed in your last catch block, it means that ZIPFoundation can't access the file at `url`. Can you check if your app has access to that particular file with some built-in API. e.g.: guard let content = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return }
If this also fails, it's simply a permission problem. (Is your url pointing to a file outside of your app's container?)

Comment: Yes I do have access to this content, `content` is initialized properly using the above code.

Comment: Your entry path is missing a path separator. While you use .appending("/license.lcpl") in your print statement, you don't add a "/" to the first argument of addEntry.

Comment: Damn stupid me... It fixed it. Thanks a lot Thomas!

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path entries in ZIP archives are not really hierarchical paths like on most modern file systems.  They are more or less just identifiers. Usually those identifiers are used to store the path that pointed to the entry on the origin file system.

The `addEntry(with path: ...)` method in ZIPFoundation is just a convenience method for the above use case.
For example, let's say we want to add an entry from a file that has the following path on a physical file system:

```
/temp/x/fileA.txt
```

If we want to use a relative path to identify the `fileA.txt` entry within the archive, we could use:

```
archive.addEntry(with: "x/fileA.txt", relativeTo: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/temp/")
```

Later, this would allow us to look up the entry with:

```
archive["x/fileA.txt"]
```

If we don't want to keep any path information except the filename, we could use:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/temp/x/fileA.txt"
archive.addEntry(with: url.lastPathComponent, relativeTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

This would allow us to look up the entry just using the filename:

```
archive["fileA.txt"]
```

If you need more control over the path/filename, you can use the [closure based API in ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation#closure-based-reading-and-writing). This is especially useful if your entry contents come from memory or you want to add entries from files that don't have a common parent directory.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer, I'll try again and let you know the results

Comment: Ok, so actually that's what I was doing, but I have this error `Error  Code=257 "The file xx couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."`. I open the archive using the `.update`mode though. Am I still missing something? edit: I'm on simulator, if that's enter in play

Comment: Do you get that error for the file you try to add? If you update your question with code, I can have a look.

Comment: This error is about the archive (an epub). I'll edit the question right now